# Excel find if string contains substring exactly once

Tags: excel, string, search, excel-formula, substring

I have a list of 3 substrings. "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"
I would like to know if Cell A2 contains just one of them exactly once. Meaning if I have "Apple" I cant' have another "Apple" or one of the other substrings in A2 again.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I edited my question with an image of what I'm trying to achieve in column B

Comment: Possibly using a formula like: `=COUNT(1/(((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"Apple","Banana","Orange"},""))))=LEN({"Apple","Banana","Orange"})))=1`

Comment: Hi it worked for me, very simple.

Answer (score 3):

It appears these substrings are sub-directories in a path. Therefor you could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")={"Apple","Banana","Orange"}))=1
```

Comment: This assumes that the string in A2 contains precisely two "/" characters. Otherwise SUMPRODUCT will attempt to compare a horizontal array of 3 entries with one containing some other number of entries, and so error.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I made the assumption we are talking sub-directories here. So it's neither the root, nor the filename and as such per definition there will be two forward slashes. Btw, there should be no error produced, but rather a "0" if no matches occur. If that is not the case it means I messed up (once again) the array-syntax and the semi-colons will have to be replaced by comma's.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Yes, my version uses the semicolon as vertical separator, hence the errors. Perhaps you should clarify that you intend the fruits to be contained in a horizontal array?

Comment: @JosWoolley, it should really be compared to a horizontal array, therefor the semi-colons should work with en-US versions of Excel at least. My locale demands the backslash to be the seperator. So my intention is really for it to be a horizontal array, not vertical.

Comment: Sorry, just realised my mistake. In English-language versions of Excel, the semicolon is the vertical separator, not horizontal. I require the comma as the separator in the array constant for your formula to not error.

Comment: In that case I know that I should add the comma's instead of semi-colon for most people visiting to know what they should pick =)

Comment: Hey what about the suggestion by @Rory: =COUNT(1/(((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"Apple","Banana","Orange"},""))))=LEN({"Apple","Banana","Orange"})))=1, it worked for me i beilieve

Comment: @Kobe2424, sure, whatever works for you but that may also include false positives as far as I can see right now.

Comment: @JvdV How would it include false positives?

Comment: @Rory, 1st of I havent attempted your suggestion but would it not count a false positive when you replace apple in apples for example. Any string that has one of the three substrings in it may be a potential false positive.

Comment: @JvdV Fair point, though looks unlikely from the examples. Could just add slashes to beginning and end by the looks of it.